# Variable that contains a string is empty when passed through an onclick function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to pass a string into a function using the onclick Event. However when I click the link the variable inside the function returns nothing. It is empty. I have no issues when I pass a number as an argument and that is displayed in the alert with no issues. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
for (var j=0;j<current_order.length;j++){   
    var note_id = "note" + (j+1);
    text = text + "<button onClick= 'deleteItemfromOrder("+j+")'>Delete</button>";  
    text = text + "<a id = '"+note_id+"' onClick= 'toggleNote("+note_id+")'>Notes</a>";
    alert(text);
}
```

This is the function I am trying to pass note_id to:

```
function toggleNote(showHideDiv) {
    alert(showHideDiv);
}
```

I have tried multiple methods to pass the string as an argument to the function EG:

```
text = text + "<a id = '"+note_id+"' onClick= 'toggleNote('"+note_id+"')'>Notes</a>";
```

and

```
text = text + "<a id = '"+note_id+"' onClick= 'toggleNote(\'"+note_id+"\;)'>Notes</a>";
```

However every time the string appears empty on the other side in the function. There is no issues if I pass a number eg:

```
text = text + "<a id = '"+note_id+"' onClick= 'toggleNote("+2+")'>Notes</a>";
```

Comment: Also can someone say why this has been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're missing quotes, numbers don't need quotes, as in

```
onclick='toggleNote(3)'
```

but a string does

```
onclick='toggleNote("string")'
```

Also, using the same quotes won't work either

```
onclick='toggleNote('string')'
```

meaning you have to do

```
text = text + "<a id = '"+note_id+"' onClick= 'toggleNote(\""+note_id+"\")'>Notes</a>";
```

But really what you should do, is create elements

```
for (var j = 0; j < current_order.length; j++) {
    (function(i) {
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        var anc = document.createElement('a');

        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            deleteItemfromOrder(i);
        });

        btn.textContent = 'Delete';

        anc.addEventListener('click', function() {
            toggleNote("note" + (i+1))
        });

        anc.textContent = 'Notes';
    })(j);
}
```

Comment: or just reference the id and do not worry about passing the string.

Comment: That works great. Everywhere I looked however they use single quotes and speech mark like double quotes for strings in javascript. How do I know when and where to use the different ones and when to use escaping I think its called ( these \ backslashes).

Comment: @FKhan - if you have an attribute, and that attribute uses single quotes, anything inside it must use double quotes, otherwise the attribute is closed when you add a single quote, and since your string is defined with doublequotes in javascript, they must be escaped to not close the string literal.